# Food Safety mould on raw beets

Tags: food-safety

I opened my bag of beets and there is a bit of mold on some of them.  Are they safe to cook and eat.  Also are they safe to use for pickled beets?

Comment: I just carve it off and eat the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you can cut out the moldy parts and the mold has not moved deep into the beet then yes. Just make sure you cut it all out.